# Newton Raphson method - While loop doesnt cancel

Tags: loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, root, infinite

I am trying to program a Newton Raphson algorithm to find the root of a function. In order to have sufficient accuracy, I enter an interval "eps" so that the root will be given out only after the error is smaller than "eps". The initial x-starting point is set by me to 1.5.

```
double func(double x) {

    return x * x * x - 4 * x + 1;
}

double funcprime(double x) {

    return 3 * x * x - 4;
}

int main()
{
    double x_start = 1.5;
    double x0= x_start - ((func(x_start)) / (funcprime(x_start)));
    double eps = abs(x_start - x0);


    while (eps > 0.000001) {

        x0 = x_start - ((func(x_start)) / (funcprime(x_start)));

        double eps = abs(x_start - x0);

        //Following line is there to analyze the problem
        cout << "x0= " << x0 <<" " << "x_start= " << x_start << " "<< "eps= " << eps << endl;

        x_start = x0;                       
    }

    cout << x0;

    return 0;

}
```

The problem I'm having lies in the while loop. Although after about 4 iterations, eps is already smaller than 0.000001 and even shown to me as eps=0, the while loop doesn't cancel and continues forever. I hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinitialize the eps(as double) inside the while loop. So remove double before eps = abs(x_start - x0) inside the while loop.

**Corrected code:**

```
double func(double x) {

    return x * x * x - 4 * x + 1;
}

double funcprime(double x) {

    return 3 * x * x - 4;
}

int main()
{
    double x_start = 1.5;
    double x0= x_start - ((func(x_start)) / (funcprime(x_start)));
    double eps = abs(x_start - x0);


    while (eps > 0.000001) {

        x0 = x_start - ((func(x_start)) / (funcprime(x_start)));

        eps = abs(x_start - x0);  // double removed here

        //Following line is there to analyze the problem
        cout << "x0= " << x0 <<" " << "x_start= " << x_start << " "<< "eps= " << eps << endl;

        x_start = x0;                       
    }

    cout << x0;

    return 0;


}
```